# Error: More than One Remote Source not Supported while running python Script on aws Instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I am trying to  transfer a python script from my local machine to the EC2 instance and try running it.

For that i tried following command in my window terminal:

```
    pscp -i C:/Users/Desktop/xyz.pem C:/Users/Desktop/script.py ec2-user.amazonaws.com :/home/ec2-user
```

The Error i am getting is : More than one remote source not supported

Answer (score 1):

check your remote host "ec2-user.amazonaws.com" i think the name is not correct, try to use ec2 public IP address or public DNS

you need to use somthing like:

```
ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

more info:
[Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses)

Comment: ec2-user is my username

Comment: and you should use `username@hostname:/file/path`

Comment: '203-0-113-25' it should be DNS or IP?

Comment: that is a name auto generated by AWS when you start your ec2 instance